# Accessing the new External Image Save functionality using Python

Tags: python

As Gandalf3 recently pointed out, Campbell has recently added code that allows for saving images externally. 
This sounds like the feature which experimental branches of Bake-Cycles were using to save baked images automatically when a bake finished.

https://developer.blender.org/D398

I can't find it exposed in the UI so I assume for now it's hidden until this is all sorted out.

This would be very useful for batch baking in scenes that already have dozens or more textures since finding everything that has just been baked can be difficult.

Does anyone have some script ideas on a simple way to access this new feature so that all images are checked for changes and saved if changes have been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch adds an additional option to the *Save as mainfile* operator:

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(external=True)
```

In a build with this patch applied, the option should show as checkbox in the side panel in the file navigator if you use *Save as...* or *Save Copy...*

Comment: That clears it up, I did not realize that we'd have to use a patch.  Campbell wrote in the comments "update to master" and I thought this meant that it already has been added.

Comment: As an update, I applied the patch and it works as expected.  This is really nice to have for batch baking.

Comment: "updated to master" means he rebased it, so it's possible to apply the patch to master without causing conflicts. "Merged / applied to master" would mean it is in trunk.